# Get old-style help in Matlab's command window

Tags: matlab

### Short version of question

In recent versions of Matlab (I have seen it in R2014b and R2015a on Windows), when you type `help foo` you get a **brief description** of the function and its signatures. For example, typing `help bsxfun` produces something like this (only with better format):

> This MATLAB function applies the element-by-element binary operation specified by the function handle `fun` to arrays `A` and `B`, with singleton expansion enabled.
>
> ```
> C = bsxfun(fun,A,B)
> ```
>
> Reference page for `bsxfun`
>
> See also `arrayfun`, `repmat`
>
> Other uses of `bsxfun`
> `distcomp/bsxfun`

This is of course only a summary of the actual documentation. To get the **full documentation** you need to type `doc foo`. This opens the HTML help browser, which takes quite some time (at least on some computers).

**Is there a way to get the full help in the command window (thus avoiding the help browser), as it used to be in older Matlab versions?**

### Long version of question

To look into this in more detail, I'll define "old" Matlab versions as those that don't have HTML help, and "new" versions as those that do. I also need to give each type of help a name, in order to refer to them:

- **FP** (Full, Plain): full help in the form of plain text, shown in Matlab command window (old style).
- **SH** (Summarized, HTML): summarized help in the form of HTML, shown in Matlab command window.
- **FH** (Full, HTML): full help in the form of HTML, shown in the help browser.

As is well known, the text for FP help is contained in the **first comment lines** in the file defining the function. In new Matlab versions, functions may also have an **associated HTML file**. This file contains SH help in an HTML tag, and FH help in HTML code.

Possible behaviour is:

- In old Matlab versions, `help foo` produced FP help.
- In new Matlab versions, `help foo` produces SH help if `foo` has an associated HTML help file, and FP help if it doesn't.
- In new Matlab versions, `doc foo` produces FH help if `foo` has an associated HTML help file. If it doesn't, FP help is shown in the help browser (without format).

So the problem is more properly phrased as: **how to show FP help in new Matlab versions when `foo` has an associated HTML help file**. The question is meaningful because

- Most Matlab functions do have an associated HTML help file.
- Most Matlab functions, even built-in functions (that have no m-code), have and m-file containing FP help.

An additional motivation is that in some cases the FP documentation contains features that don't appear in the FH documentation (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29111291/2586922)).

Comment: What OS are you using? I don't see this behavior for `help bsxfun` on OS X 10.10.2 and R2015a. Could it be related to the browser / HTML renderer used?

Comment: @horchler I see it in R2014b on Windows 7 64 bits, and also in R2015a on Windows Vista 32 bits. I thought it would be the same on all operating systems. So what do you get on OS X? Do `help bsxfun` and `disp(help('bsxfun'))` produce the same output?

Comment: The result of `help bsxfun` and `disp(help('bsxfun'))` is the same except the latter is all plain text (links at bottom are no longer links). Another factor that could be related might be your version of Java. I'm using 1.7.0_60-b19.

Comment: @horchler I have that same Java version. So it may be a Windows-specific thing. Weird

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Original answer (Matlab versions R2014b, R2015a)

Although the documentation doesn't tell, the `help` function in these Matlab versions supports zero, one or two output arguments. You can check this typing `open help` and looking at the function signature:

```
function [out, docTopic] = help(varargin)
```

In essence, `help` works internally as follows:

1. It creates an object called `process`, of class `helpUtils.helpProcess`, by calling the class constructor as:

   ```
   process = helpUtils.helpProcess(nargout, nargin, varargin);
   ```

   where `nargout`, `argin` and `varargin` are those with which `help` was called.
2. It runs the method `process.getHelpText`, which calls the undocumented, built-in function `helpfunc`, and as a result sets the property `process.helpStr`. This property contains the help string which is shown in the command window.

As it turns out, at least on Windows, **depending on the value of `nargout`** (which gets passed to the constructor `helpUtils.helpProcess`) **the resulting help string will be FP or SH**. Namely, it will be FP if `nargout>0`, and SH if `nargout==0`. You can check this by typing the following code (adapted from `help.m`) directly in the command window:

```
process = helpUtils.helpProcess(1, 1, {'bsxfun'});
process.getHelpText
process.helpStr
```

This will produce FP help. On the other hand, changing the first `1` (which corresponds to `nargout` in the actual call) into a `0`,

```
process = helpUtils.helpProcess(0, 1, {'bsxfun'});
process.getHelpText
process.helpStr
```

will produce SH help.

I don't know why this is so, that is, how it works on a deeper level than this. All I know is that the `getHelp` method calls the undocumented `helpfunc`, which is at least involved in producing FP help.

So, **to get FP help you need to call `help` with one or two output arguments**. For example,

```
str = help('foo')
```

assigns the FP help text to variable `str` and displays it. Or you can use

```
disp(help('foo'))
```

which also has the effect of calling `help` with an (implicit) output argument.

**To have this behaviour from the standard command `help foo`**, you could define a `help` function to **override Matlab's `help`**, and place it in your Matlab document folder. This folder normally appears first in the path (or you can make sure it does by editing `startup.m`), and thus has precedence. The new function will essentially call Matlab's `help` with one output argument, and then display the resulting (FP) help text. In order to call the overriden function it is necessary to temporarily change to its folder:

```
function help(varargin)
if isempty(varargin)
    varargin = {'help'}; %// `help` should be equivalent to `help help`
end
d = pwd; %// take note of current folder
cd(fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', 'matlab', 'helptools')) %// folder where the
    %// standard `help` function is
disp(help(varargin{1}));
cd(d) %// restore folder
```

So now, finally, `help foo` produces the old-style (FP) help.

## Edit for Matlab version R2015b

In Matlab R2015b the behaviour seems to have changed for the better. Typing `help foo` no longer produces SH help. It's not exactly FP either. In fact it's better than that: it produces FH help but in the command Window, not in the browser. Or, equivalently, it produces FP help but with links and better formattting.

So no need to tweak anymore!

## Edit for Matlab version R2018a

Matlab R2018a again gives SH help. The solution provided in this answer works (that is, produces FP help).

So back to tweaking!

Comment: Great find. The HTML-doc annoys me too sometimes. Ironically `help help` isn't helpful at all. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp Thanks! On my computer, opening the help browser takes foreeeever :-) And you also lose some time changing windows

Answer (score 4):

A better way is to include the full path to the function when using the `help` command, then old style full help is displayed and **the links also work**, e.g. try:

```
help surf
help(fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', 'matlab', 'graph3d', 'surf.m'))
```

I’ve just submitted an **override** `help` function based on this to MATLAB FEX:[Full Command Line Help](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51201-full-command-line-help)

Comment: Nice find! Have you checked R2015b? Now `help surf` displays old style full help with links. No need for tweaking anymore, apparently