# Simple way to get more sensible colors in gscatter

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure

I'm looking for a simple way to get `gscatter` to choose more sensible colors.

As you can see in the picture below, groups 3 and 4 have very similar colors, which are difficult to distinguish.

I'm plotting my data using `gscatter(X(:,1),X(:,4),assigns , [], [] )`.

I know I can use `scatter` to manually get more sensible colors by creating a colormap that has the same number of colors as the number of groups I have, but then how do I get a nice legend like gscatter produces without looping over each group?

So, is there a simple(r) way to get more sensible colors with `gscatter`?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fourth argument of `gscatter` is the color specification. According to the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html), only letters can be used to define the colors:

> `gscatter(x,y,group,clr,sym,siz)` specifies the color, marker type, and size for each group. **`clr` is a string array of colors recognized by the `plot` function**. The default for `clr` is `'bgrcmyk'`.

But if you type `open gscatter` and look at the comments in the first lines (Matlab's [old-style help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953661/get-old-style-help-in-matlabs-command-window)), surprise!

> GSCATTER(X,Y,G,CLR,SYM,SIZ) specifies the colors, markers, and 
>     size to use.  CLR is either a string of color specifications **or 
>
>     a three-column matrix of color specifications**.

So you can use a colormap matrix to define the colors you want (at least in Matlab R2014b).

Example:

```
load discrim
group(1:3:end) = 3; %// borrowing Benoit_11's idea to create two more groups
group(2:2:end) = 4;
cmap = hsv(4); %// define your colormap here
gscatter(ratings(:,1), ratings(:,2), group, cmap)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**: In newer Matlab versions (I checked R2019a) the documentation does mention the possibility to specify the colors as a three-column matrix:

> `clr`: Marker colors: character vector or string scalar of colors | **matrix of RGB triplet values**.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer for it is indeed simpler. +1 for you, -1 for undocumented features :-(

Comment: @CassioPereira Well, in this case I wouldn't say they are undocumented features. It's just that they are documented in a hidden place :-)

Comment: @Benoit_11 Thanks! Your solution is actually very good too (+1 already)

Answer (score 4):

Here is some kind of trade-off in which you do use `gscatter` and its nice legend functionality but you need to loop through each group to set a color manually, if you want.

The trick is to assign an output during the call to `gscatter` and afterward change the `Color` property. You can of course change any property you want.

In the simple example, I generate random colors for each group but you could easily access entries of a custom colormap with the colors you need.:

```
clear
clc
close all

load discrim

%// Just creating 2 more groups for the demo.
group(1:3:end) = 3;
group(2:2:end) = 4;

figure;

%// Retrieve handles of the scatter plot
hScatter = gscatter(ratings(:,1),ratings(:,2),group);

%// Set colors manually. You can use your own colormap.
for k = 1:numel(hScatter)
set(hScatter(k),'Color',rand(1,3))
end

xlabel('climate');
ylabel('housing');
```

Output:

[image]